# Uisegmentedbar fixed above uitableview

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController subclass and it appears in a navigation stack however I want to add a view (uisegmentedcontrol) to above the tableview like in the AppStore when you go into categories and drill down un a list of apps there is a segmented control with paid free and grossing. If you scroll the tableview it stays attached to the navbar. Unlike adding a view to the table header which means it scrolls with the content which is not what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best option is to create a `UIViewController`, then add a `UISegmentedControl` then a `UITableView`.